# Creating a view after with clause

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have an extremely complicated query that I need to answer in several steps. First, I create a view  by running an sql file (say a.sql) and the generated view is used in a separate query in a second sql file (say b.sql). I am having some trouble creating the view in a.sql file.

In the a.sql file, I am trying to first use a WITH clause and then I am trying to generating a view something like the following (I am simplifying in order to understand what I am doing wrong). Say my table named tab has two fields, id and age. I am getting syntax error when I try to do the following. Are such operations not allowed in mysql/postgresql? What am I doing wrong in the following code?

Clearly, this particular example can be solved in efficient way without using the WITH clause and directly creating a view. But the main purpose of my question is to understand whether WITH clause followed by CREATE VIEW is syntactically allowed or not.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```sql
WITH aa AS  
(  
 SELECT t.id AS id, t.age AS age 
 FROM tab t  
 WHERE t.age>18  
)

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS bb;  
CREATE VIEW bb AS  
(  
 SELECT a.id, a.age  
 FROM aa a  
 WHERE a.age>25  
)
```

Comment: I can't speak for postgresql, but Views in MySQL appear to offer no practical advantage.

Comment: Why do you use Views in this case?

Comment: The `WITH` clause is part of a single `SELECT` statement, one such clause cannot be used for several SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can create a view with WITH clause like below

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS bb; 

CREATE VIEW bb 
AS 
  WITH aa 
       AS (SELECT * 
           FROM   (VALUES (12, 320)) x(t, c)) 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   aa
```